# Steady state Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, matrix, markov-process

is it able to count the steady state of problem with recurrent subchain.. for example if there are A B C D things and they are all recurrent. do they have steady state??

and also.. how to count steady state if the problem uses 4x4 or bigger matrix??
because ive searched about steady state and most of them only give example of 2x2 matrix..

Answer (score 1):

For a transition matrix $P$, you find the stationary distribution by solving the equation $\nu=\nu P$, i.e. the solution is the one that remains the same after a single pass on the chain. The number of solutions will be the number of stationary distributions, and it depends on the rank of the matrix $P$, which depends on the number of recurrent states etc. In the solution you also need $\nu$ to be a distribution, i.e. sum to 1 and positive.